# How to track an objects state in time?

Tags: python

In my script I read messages from socket and change the state of some objects in memory depending on the content in message. Everything works fine.

But I want to implement deletion of non-active objects: for example, if there's no message for specified object during some time, it should be deleted. What is the best way to do it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This one might not work for you, but:
if you're okay with not removing objects after a specified time, but only keeping a specified *number* of objects, Python 3.2 has [functools.lru_cache](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) for exactly that.

Comment: +1 Limiting the number of objects may actually be a much better choice: It keeps memory usage low if lots of objects are accessed during busy peroids and doesn't delete objects when there simply aren't any requests for a brief period.

Comment: The Python 3.2 requirement is probably a stronger reason against. (Although it's quite possible to adapt from Python 3's [functools](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/default/Lib/functools.py#l123).)

Answer (score 1):

Store a timestamp in each object - update the timestamp to the current time whenever you modify it.

Then have something that runs every so often, looks at all of the objects, and removes any with a timestamp earlier than a certain amount before the current time.

Answer (score 1):

If you're stuck with Python 2, or if you need this to be timestamp-based and Amber's answer isn't fast enough, you can do a variation on what Python 3's lru_cache does, but take the object's modification time into account:

(I didn't test this; hopefully the bugs are minor and the idea is clear.)

---

Store the objects in an [OrderedDict](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) (there's a [package](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ordereddict) for Pythons older than 2.7).

```
import collections
objects = collections.OrderedDict()
```

I assume you have some key for each object so you can identify them in the stream. Do a variation of a regular lookup that removes and re-inserts an already existing object from the dict. This will keep the OrderedDict sorted by last access.

```
try:
    obj = objects.pop(the_key)
except KeyError:
    obj = create_new_object(the_key)
objects[the_key] = obj
obj.timestamp = current_time()
```

Then, every once in a while (or every time), remove the old objects. The LRU variant (limiting the *number* of objects) is easy enough:

```
while len(objects) > some_threshold:
    objects.popitem(last=False)
```

The timestamp-based variant is a bit trickier, but not much. The oldest entries are in the front, so we only have to look at the first one, and pop it if it's too ancient.

```
while objects:
    obj = objects.itervalues().next()  # Python 2 only :(
    if obj.timestamp < some_threshold():
        objects.popitem(last=False)
    else:
        break
```

An eyeball analysis says that this gives you amortized O(1) access, and O(number of discarded objects) upkeep in both variants.